# RSA Signature verification works on .Net core but not on .Net 4.8

Tags: c#, .net-core, rsa, digital-signature

I have a very simple .Net console app that i will paste here, that does RSA signature validation and works perfectly on .Net Core 3.1. But the exact same code (copy paste no changes) on a .net 4.8 console app says the signature is invalid.

I have no idea what's going on. This signature is ok in all other languages i tested and even online RSA signature validators.

Using Nuget BouncyCastle 1.8.6.1 on both.

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;


    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            byte[] publicKeyData = Convert.FromBase64String("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");
            string decodedPublicKeyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(publicKeyData);
            string signedData = "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";
            var signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signedData);
            VerifyWithPublicKey("12345789", signedBytes, decodedPublicKeyString);
        }

        private static bool VerifyWithPublicKey(string data, byte[] signedHash, string decodedPublicKey)
        {
            try
            {
                using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
                {
                    byte[] hash;

                    using (SHA256 shaM = SHA256.Create())
                    {
                        hash = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
                    }

                    using (var keyreader = new StringReader(decodedPublicKey))
                    {
                        var pemReader = new PemReader(keyreader);
                        var y = (RsaKeyParameters)pemReader.ReadObject();
                        var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
                        rsaParameters.Modulus = y.Modulus.ToByteArray();
                        rsaParameters.Exponent = y.Exponent.ToByteArray();
                        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

                        RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter RSADeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);
                        RSADeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

                        if (RSADeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, signedHash))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The signature was verified.");
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The signature was not verified.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Microsoft keeps on changing default parameters for each version of Net Library.  So usually they set to latest/greatest which make OPs have to modify code for each version of Net.  Either the RsaKeyParameters or the RSA encryption mode has changed.  You can put break points in your code and compare the Core and 4.8 parameters to see what changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run on my machine yields `false` both for 4.6.2 and 4.7.2. However, changing

```
rsaParameters.Modulus = y.Modulus.ToByteArray();
rsaParameters.Exponent = y.Exponent.ToByteArray();
```

to

```
rsaParameters.Modulus = y.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
rsaParameters.Exponent = y.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
```

seems to correct the issue. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Well it works, i won't know why it works in .netcore without that change, but good enough for me.